# how to access a private npm package via github actions?

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions

I think this is a pretty straightforward question. Still, I'm finding lots of different resources suggesting going down different paths, installing different things, and generally speaking, so far everything seems all over the place.

In my case, I made a private package on npm. I'm trying to do a basic `on push to main > run ci and build` github action. However, I have my own custom *private* npm package, part of an org I made on npm. When the pipeline triggers I get the following response:

[image]

The current `node.js.yml` file looks like so:

```
name: Node.js CI

env:
  NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
  pull_request:
    branches: ['main']

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: echo "Running pipeline."
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test
```

There's not enough information in it yet, other than a `read-only` key provide (per npm docs), but I don't know if that's a step in the right direction or if I need to do something entirely different. As I said, I'm not too familiar with this space and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add an `.npmrc` file, with NPM_TOKEN as a github secret.

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `.npmrc` file with proper `authToken`.

Add your `authToken` to your GitHub Environemnt Secrets (for example as: `NPM_TOKEN`) and then use to create a file using bash script for example:

```
- name: "Create .npmrc"
  run: |
    echo "registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}" >> .npmrc
```

Then you can call `npm install`.